# Wpf combo box focus/ mouse over. How to change the background colour?

Tags: wpf, combobox

I'm having trouble with changing the background colour of a combobox when it receives focus, and on mouseover. I would of thought this should be reasonably straightforward, but I'm stumped.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}" >
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                </Trigger>
               <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

It won't work because of the default `ControlTemplate` on `ComboBox`.  `ComboBox` consists of two parts, `TextBox` and `Popup`.  The way you're doing it, it'll affect only the `TextBox`... but temporarily.  So, if you mouseover the combobox, you'll notice that your background takes affect and then it disappears.  That's because the default `ControlTemplate` has that animating behavior overriding your new background.

The easiest way to customize a `ComboBox` is to define a new template.  You may find an example here (from MSDN):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752094(v=vs.110).aspx

In case you're having issues with the link, here's an example of a `ControlTemplate` for the `ComboBox`:

```
<!--Control colors.-->
<Color x:Key="WindowColor">#FFE8EDF9</Color>
<Color x:Key="ContentAreaColorLight">#FFC5CBF9</Color>
<Color x:Key="ContentAreaColorDark">#FF7381F9</Color>

<Color x:Key="DisabledControlLightColor">#FFE8EDF9</Color>
<Color x:Key="DisabledControlDarkColor">#FFC5CBF9</Color>
<Color x:Key="DisabledForegroundColor">#FF888888</Color>

<Color x:Key="SelectedBackgroundColor">#FFC5CBF9</Color>
<Color x:Key="SelectedUnfocusedColor">#FFDDDDDD</Color>

<Color x:Key="ControlLightColor">White</Color>
<Color x:Key="ControlMediumColor">#FF7381F9</Color>
<Color x:Key="ControlDarkColor">#FF211AA9</Color>

<Color x:Key="ControlMouseOverColor">#FF3843C4</Color>
<Color x:Key="ControlPressedColor">#FF211AA9</Color>


<Color x:Key="GlyphColor">#FF444444</Color>
<Color x:Key="GlyphMouseOver">sc#1, 0.004391443, 0.002428215, 0.242281124</Color>

<!--Border colors-->
<Color x:Key="BorderLightColor">#FFCCCCCC</Color>
<Color x:Key="BorderMediumColor">#FF888888</Color>
<Color x:Key="BorderDarkColor">#FF444444</Color>

<Color x:Key="PressedBorderLightColor">#FF888888</Color>
<Color x:Key="PressedBorderDarkColor">#FF444444</Color>

<Color x:Key="DisabledBorderLightColor">#FFAAAAAA</Color>
<Color x:Key="DisabledBorderDarkColor">#FF888888</Color>

<Color x:Key="DefaultBorderBrushDarkColor">Black</Color>

<!--Control-specific resources.-->
<Color x:Key="HeaderTopColor">#FFC5CBF9</Color>
<Color x:Key="DatagridCurrentCellBorderColor">Black</Color>
<Color x:Key="SliderTrackDarkColor">#FFC5CBF9</Color>

<Color x:Key="NavButtonFrameColor">#FF3843C4</Color>

<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="MenuPopupBrush"
                     EndPoint="0.5,1"
                     StartPoint="0.5,0">
  <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlLightColor}"
                Offset="0" />
  <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlMediumColor}"
                Offset="0.5" />
  <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlLightColor}"
                Offset="1" />
</LinearGradientBrush>

<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ProgressBarIndicatorAnimatedFill"
                     StartPoint="0,0"
                     EndPoint="1,0">
  <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
    <GradientStopCollection>
      <GradientStop Color="#000000FF"
                    Offset="0" />
      <GradientStop Color="#600000FF"
                    Offset="0.4" />
      <GradientStop Color="#600000FF"
                    Offset="0.6" />
      <GradientStop Color="#000000FF"
                    Offset="1" />
    </GradientStopCollection>
  </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
</LinearGradientBrush>

<ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxToggleButton"
                 TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
  <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
      <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
        <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
        <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
          <Storyboard>
            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).
                (GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)"
                                          Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
              <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                   Value="{StaticResource ControlMouseOverColor}" />
            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
          </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
        <VisualState x:Name="Pressed" />
        <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
          <Storyboard>
            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).
                (GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)"
                                          Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
              <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                   Value="{StaticResource DisabledControlDarkColor}" />
            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).
                (SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                          Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow">
              <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                   Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundColor}" />
            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).
                (GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)"
                                          Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
              <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                   Value="{StaticResource DisabledBorderDarkColor}" />
            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
          </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
      </VisualStateGroup>
      <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
        <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
          <Storyboard>
            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).
                (GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)"
                                          Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
              <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                   Value="{StaticResource ControlPressedColor}" />
            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
          </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
        <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked" />
        <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate" />
      </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <Border x:Name="Border"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
            CornerRadius="2"
            BorderThickness="1">
      <Border.BorderBrush>
        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1"
                             StartPoint="0,0">
          <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource BorderLightColor}"
                        Offset="0" />
          <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource BorderDarkColor}"
                        Offset="1" />
        </LinearGradientBrush>
      </Border.BorderBrush>
      <Border.Background>

        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0"
                             EndPoint="0,1">
          <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
            <GradientStopCollection>
              <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlLightColor}" />
              <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlMediumColor}"
                            Offset="1.0" />
            </GradientStopCollection>
          </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
        </LinearGradientBrush>

      </Border.Background>
    </Border>
    <Border Grid.Column="0"
            CornerRadius="2,0,0,2"
            Margin="1" >
        <Border.Background>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource ControlLightColor}"/>
        </Border.Background>
    </Border>
    <Path x:Name="Arrow"
          Grid.Column="1"
          HorizontalAlignment="Center"
          VerticalAlignment="Center"
          Data="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 8 0 Z" >
        <Path.Fill>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource GlyphColor}"/>
        </Path.Fill>
    </Path>
  </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>

<ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxTextBox"
                 TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
  <Border x:Name="PART_ContentHost"
          Focusable="False"
          Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
</ControlTemplate>

<Style x:Key="{x:Type ComboBox}"
       TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
  <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels"
          Value="true" />
  <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle"
          Value="true" />
  <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility"
          Value="Auto" />
  <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility"
          Value="Auto" />
  <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll"
          Value="true" />
  <Setter Property="MinWidth"
          Value="120" />
  <Setter Property="MinHeight"
          Value="20" />
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
        <Grid>
          <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
              <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
              <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver" />
              <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                <Storyboard>
                  <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox"
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.Foreground).
                      (SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                         Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundColor}" />
                  </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="EditStates">
              <VisualState x:Name="Editable">
                <Storyboard>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)"
                                                 Storyboard.TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                            Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                      Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)"
                                                 Storyboard.TargetName="ContentSite">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                            Value="{x:Static Visibility.Hidden}" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
              <VisualState x:Name="Uneditable" />
            </VisualStateGroup>
          </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
          <ToggleButton x:Name="ToggleButton"
                        Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButton}"
                        Grid.Column="2"
                        Focusable="false"
                        ClickMode="Press"
                        IsChecked="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, 
              RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
          <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite"
                            IsHitTestVisible="False"
                            Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}"
                            ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}"
                            ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}"
                            Margin="3,3,23,3"
                            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left">
          </ContentPresenter>
          <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox"
                   Style="{x:Null}"
                   Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxTextBox}"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                   VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                   Margin="3,3,23,3"
                   Focusable="True"
                   Background="Transparent"
                   Visibility="Hidden"
                   IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}" />
          <Popup x:Name="Popup"
                 Placement="Bottom"
                 IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}"
                 AllowsTransparency="True"
                 Focusable="False"
                 PopupAnimation="Slide">
            <Grid x:Name="DropDown"
                  SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                  MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}"
                  MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}">
              <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder"
                      BorderThickness="1">
                <Border.BorderBrush>
                  <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource BorderMediumColor}" />
                </Border.BorderBrush>
                <Border.Background>
                  <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource ControlLightColor}" />
                </Border.Background>
              </Border>
              <ScrollViewer Margin="4,6,4,6"
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True"
                            KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" />
              </ScrollViewer>
            </Grid>
          </Popup>
        </Grid>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="HasItems"
                   Value="false">
            <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder"
                    Property="MinHeight"
                    Value="95" />
          </Trigger>
          <Trigger Property="IsGrouping"
                   Value="true">
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll"
                    Value="false" />
          </Trigger>
          <Trigger SourceName="Popup"
                   Property="AllowsTransparency"
                   Value="true">
            <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder"
                    Property="CornerRadius"
                    Value="4" />
            <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder"
                    Property="Margin"
                    Value="0,2,0,0" />
          </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}"
       TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
  <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels"
          Value="true" />
  <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle"
          Value="true" />
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
        <Border x:Name="Border"
                Padding="2"
                SnapsToDevicePixels="true"
                Background="Transparent">
          <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
              <VisualState x:Name="Unselected" />
              <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                <Storyboard>
                  <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).
                    (SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                         Value="{StaticResource SelectedBackgroundColor}" />
                  </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
              <VisualState x:Name="SelectedUnfocused">
                <Storyboard>
                  <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).
                    (SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                         Value="{StaticResource SelectedUnfocusedColor}" />
                  </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
          </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
          <ContentPresenter />
        </Border>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

If you're new to control templates, don't get intimidated by its size. Simply read through what it's showing and you'll see that it's actually very simple.  **Blend** can make your life even easier, as it makes the routine of working with templates very simple and will actually let you edit a copy of the default template when you select to edit the existing template.